# Inserting result of radio buttons values evaluation into database using

Tags: database, vb.net, radio-button

What is the code for inserting the radio buttons in database using vb.net? I've tried this one but it didn't work. Help me. Sorry for my poor grammar.

```
Dim s As Boolean

If optADD_A.Checked = True Then
    s = True
ElseIf optADD_B.Checked = True And optADD_C.Checked = True And optADD_D.Checked = True Then
    s = False
End If

If optADD_B.Checked = True Then
    s = True
ElseIf optADD_A.Checked = True And optADD_C.Checked = True And optADD_D.Checked = True Then
    s = False
End If

If optADD_C.Checked = True Then
    s = True
Else
    s = False
End If

If optADD_D.Checked = True Then
    s = True
Else
    s = False
End If

sql = "INSERT INTO tblAdd(Answer)VALUES('" & s & "')"

Dim cmd As New OledbCommand(sql,con)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: NOTE: I HAD 4 RADIOBUTTONS AS A CHOICES TO MY WORK

Comment: If any option is true, your follow on tests are undoing it.  Set a breakpoint and watch the code execute and you'll see.  You need an `If...ElseIf....ElseIf` block to evaluate

Comment: Is your database only going to hold information for one question?  Learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: Why would you use radio buttons? the idea of radio buttons is to pick one value. You either using check boxes or not using radio buttons right. May be you need to check each specific condition, listing all boxes in each if/else

Comment: @ T.S. Because radio buttons are better for making an Examination System instead of using checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow your logic. The answer is true when both C and D are checked and also either of A or B are checked. Also greatly simplified your code.

```
Dim s As Boolean = (optADD_A.Checked OrElse optADD_B.Checked) _
                   AndAlso optADD_C.Checked _
                   AndAlso optADD_D.Checked 

sql = "INSERT INTO tblAdd(Answer) VALUES('" & s & "')"

Dim cmd As New OledbCommand(sql, con)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```